# SQL Azure and Power BI

Tags: c#, xml, csv, azure-sql-database, powerbi

I need to design some Power BI reports which will be hosted using Azure (at present we are thinking of using azure services, if the design doesn't solve then we have to go to on premise hosting)

1. We have a remote PC (at present runs windows OS) which will collect all the report data and store in either XML or CSV file on a daily basis (Challenge here, this PC is not connected online always, have a limited and timed connectivity, when we have the connection, we push the data to server)
2. We need to push this data from this remote PC to SQL Azure
3. Using Power BI (from azure) we need to generate reports using data from SQL Azure

Now, the challenge I am facing are

1. How to push the data (either in XML or CSV) from remote PC to SQL Azure
2. How to integrate SQL Azure and Power BI

If there is any other suggestion for this we are ok as we are yet to finalize the design for app development. Also, the design should be platform independent (in case we move to Linux based remote pc)

Answer (score 0):

> How to push the data (either in XML or CSV) from remote PC to SQL Azure

Many options..

1.Use SSIS to move data to azure and it supports SQLAzure as destination as well.
2.Write a C# executable which does the task for you ,if you require much customization..

> How to integrate SQL Azure and Power BI

using Powerbi with SqlAzure is very simple,you just have to choose which your destination as shown in links below..

step by step steps:  https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-sql-database-with-direct-connect/

Powerbi has api's as well:  https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-and-power-bi/

Comment: Thank you, any sample for C# code to push data from remote PC, as we will have no option to install SSIS, rather we can write C# windows service with a watch folder and schedule to transfer the data to SQL Azure.

Comment: if you have SQLServer on onpremises,ssis packages are easy..regarding links,you may have to segregate searches and divide and conquer..below links may be helpfull..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070465/windows-service-in-c-sharp-to-read-xml-file-and-insert-data-into-database    https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/100/windows-service-to-update-record-from-one-database-to-another-after-certain-interval-of-time   https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1113/copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-using-windows-service-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you, but I see a challenge if we can use StoreProc in SQL Azure or not, it we can my approach will be good.

Comment: Sqlazure is like sqldatabase ,why do you think ,we can't use stored proc's

Comment: Because of this link - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/

Comment: I don't see any where `StoreProc` mentioned in list

Comment: its under "partially supported", not an issue, still reviewing the details you have provided me.